# Cannot open %INCLUDE file, file doesn't exist. SAS Studio

Tags: sas, include

I'm writing ODS PDF program (in SAS Studio) in which I want to put code from another .sas file so that it is more readable. So I tried with %INCLUDE like this:

```
OPTIONS NODATE ORIENTATION=landscape;
ODS PDF FILE=savePath
    CONTENTS = no BOOKMARKLIST = no STYLE=Styles.CustomHZMO;

%INCLUDE 'Dnevni_izvjestaj_OSIGURANJE_A1_V2.sas';

ODS PDF CLOSE;
```

And I get the following error and warning:

```
WARNING: Physical file does not exist, /opt/work/SAS_work3CAC0000136A_srvlx159mih/Dnevni_izvjestaj_OSIGURANJE_A1_V2.sas.
ERROR: Cannot open %INCLUDE file Dnevni_izvjestaj_OSIGURANJE_A1_V2.sas.
```

Even though both of those .sas files are in the same folder. It says the same error when i give the full path of the .sas file like this:

```
%INCLUDE '/Projects/HZMO/Jobs/Dnevni_izvjestaj_OSIGURANJE_A1_V2.sas';
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your first error shows you what happens if you make the mistake of using a RELATIVE path to the file.  Your second example looks better since now you are using an ABSOLUTE path to the file.  If SAS says the file does not exist then it does not exist.  Make sure the file exists on the machine were SAS is running. You can use the FILEEXIST() function to test if the file exists.  Is the /Projects/HZMO folder mounted on the machine where SAS is running?

Comment: If your file is relative to your Studio login folder, try `%INCLUDE '~/Projects/HZMO/Jobs/Dnevni_izvjestaj_OSIGURANJE_A1_V2.sas';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Viya and your files are saved in Viya (i.e. not physical storage mounted to the filesystem), you need to use the `filesrvc` access method to reference those files or folders. `filesrvc` is your bridge between Viya storage and SAS Studio.

Try this instead:

```
filename hzmo filesrvc
    folderpath='/Projects/HZMO/Jobs/';

%include hzmo('Dnevni_izvjestaj_OSIGURANJE_A1_V2.sas');
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing filesrvc when I tried something like that